# how to get job properties in the processor through job context in JSR

Tags: java, spring-batch, jsr

I'm passing property in Run Configuration during job execution. how to get job properties in the processor through job context in JSR . Is there is any other way to get the property in processor ?

Answer (score 0):

If your job is related to Spring Batch, then you can get job parameters as well as system properties using getJobParameters() and getSystemProperties() methods in JobContext. Below is the reference for Spring Batch Job Context API Doc

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/JobContext.html